# Response is blank while downloading a the pdf form amazonaws

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, http-headers, python-requests, request-headers

I am trying to download the pdf file from this [link](https://ap-prod-ddc-stack-content.s3.amazonaws.com/devtestbed-prod-01/ABC000128CEC2.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJZ2VLLVH5FAWOGYA&Expires=1466500635&Signature=itUWZwiOiWwH%2BPihTYMjoq1URFw%3D) using python 2.7 requests:

https://ap-prod-ddc-stack-content.s3.amazonaws.com/devtestbed-prod-01/ABC000128CEC2.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJZ2VLLVH5FAWOGYA&Expires=1466500635&Signature=itUWZwiOiWwH%2BPihTYMjoq1URFw%3D

```
import requests
headers={
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.107 Safari/537.36'
    }
download_url="https://ap-prod-ddc-stack-content.s3.amazonaws.com/devtestbed-prod-01/ABC000128CEC2.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJZ2VLLVH5FAWOGYA&Expires=1466500635&Signature=itUWZwiOiWwH%2BPihTYMjoq1URFw%3D"
response=  requests.get(download_url,headers=headers )
print response
print  "##################"
print response.content
```

In the response of **GET** request i am getting Code **200** but the content is blank.

What i am missing in my code.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. The code works fine for me.

Comment: what is content of  response.content

Comment: the binary contents of the pdf. `content` is for binary files. `text` is for text files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do next is to save the content to file as bytes (using 'wb' flag) and not as string, because the content is byte code.

**Add this to the end of your code:**

```
with open('PATH\downloaded.pdf', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(response.content)
```

**NOTE**: I used python3.4 and it worked for me.

Comment: thanks, but can you tell me how you know that content is byte code

Comment: You're welcome. I had 2 indicators: first, when you print the content it prints "b...." and the 'b' is the indication that this string is a byte string. Second, there are further information here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content